# Python: If I have a tuple (A,B), how do I take the mean all B values in ranges based on A value?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some data as a list of tuples, each containing two floats. Let's call them `(A,B)`.  A can be any positive float and B can be positive or negative.

The goal here is to take the mean of all the B values in ranges of A values (0-5, 5-10, etc.), and display those means on a matplotlib chart (something that looks like a histogram, but isn't). In other words, for the tuple (6.5, 2.1), the B value 2.1 would be included in the mean for all B values whose paired A value is in the 5-10 range.

The solution I have penciled out is to construct bins based on the range of A, then somehow sort the values of B into those bins based on the value of A.  Create the bins with:

```py
A_vals = [pairs[0] for pairs in tuple_list]
bins = range(min(A_vals), max(A_vals) + bin_width, bin_width)
```

But that's where I get stumped. My first thought was to create either a dictionary with the bin range as the key and a list of B values as the values, or create a list of lists where each sublist has the same index as the index of each bin.  However, even going over the logistics of that on paper suggested that solution to be so complex, inefficient, and inelegant that it probably wouldn't work and it would almost certainly choke on a large dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

data = [(6.5, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 6.5), (7, 1), (11, 5.5)]
data = np.array(data)

edge = data[:,0].max() // 5 * 5
bins = np.arange(0, edge, 5)
# bins contains just the lower edges

indices = np.digitize(data[:,0], bins)
unique = set(indices)
means = np.empty(len(unique), dtype=float)
for index in unique:
    bind = np.where(indices == index)
    means[index-1] = data[bind,1].mean()
print("lower edges:", bins, "upper edges:", bins+5)
print("means for each interval:", means)
```

```
lower edges: [0. 5.] upper edges: [ 5. 10.]
means for each interval: [3.5  3.75]
```

Comment: This ended up working for me. Took me a little longer to set up because I forgot that the data for A could include None, and that was causing the usage of max() to fail.  After several hours of research, I managed to circumvent the problem by using a masked array with NaNs:

```data = numpy.array(pairs)
mask = numpy.zeros(data.shape, bool) | (data[:, 0] == None)[:, None]
data = numpy.ma.masked_array(data, mask=mask, copy=False).filled(numpy.nan)
edge = numpy.nanmax(data[:, 0]) // bin_width * bin_width
```

Comment: @JohnJ.Hritz Indeed, I myself find a masked array the best way to handle Nones, assuming these indicate missing data. Instead of NaNs (which would be the result of invalid math operations, such as 0/0). Good it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of creating dictionaries with "bin ranges" isn't bad, so I will help you by providing an example implementation. I think what you were missing is a better way to cast a value into a respective range (so that all `A` values correspond to ranges `0-5`, `5-10`, and so on).

Consider the following snippet of code:

```py
# Generate data to work on
from random import random
data = [(random()*20, random()*100 - 50) for _ in range(100)]

# Based on your question it seems the "bins" accept values differing by 5
classifier_difference = 5

# This is where the mapping comes into place, using defaultdict to avoid explicit initialisation for each key
from collections import defaultdict
bins = defaultdict(list)

# Bins will now map keys 0, 5, 10, ..., to a list of values exactly as they were in B
# You can modify key creation however you want really, but classifier // classifier_difference is the key point
for classifier, value in data:
    key = int(classifier // classifier_difference) * classifier_difference
    bins[key].append(value)
```

`bins` then can be printed as:

```
0 : [-32.67530553821753, 24.35350483989876, 12.01416796389043]
5 : [8.908191728237938, -28.726927969770234, 3.3525305442688946, -28.831840180707637]
10 : [-48.54368729435071]
15 : [15.648424404193577, 33.47713312289213]
```

I will leave finding means to you as it's rather simple once you have the `list` instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with numpy's boolean indexing:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = np.random.rand(100,2) * 100
print(data)

for bucket in range(0,100,5):
    b = data[(data[:,0] > bucket) & (data[:,0] < (bucket+5)), 1]
    print( bucket, b.shape, b.sum(), b.sum() / b.shape[0] )
```

Let me explain that.  `data[:0] > bucket` produces an array of booleans that is true where the element in column 0 is greater than bucket.  `data[:0' <(bucket+5)]` does the same for the other end.  By using `&`, we get an array of booleans that is True where column 0 is in that range.

By then doing `data[booleans,1]`, we are selecting the value in column 1 for all the rows that meet the criteria.  That's what you want.

Output:

```
0 (7,) 486.0666260029982 69.43808942899975
5 (2,) 162.75938362848922 81.37969181424461
10 (6,) 404.65207867981894 67.44201311330316
15 (4,) 216.561058153033 54.14026453825825
20 (4,) 158.6933597307469 39.67333993268672
25 (10,) 590.6337605765742 59.06337605765742
30 (8,) 499.48740241702797 62.435925302128496
35 (8,) 420.51694802312426 52.56461850289053
40 (4,) 142.7888162321809 35.69720405804522
45 (5,) 257.7772788672603 51.55545577345206
50 (3,) 143.1221738596666 47.70739128655553
55 (4,) 305.4444504680107 76.36111261700268
60 (3,) 101.81220129227752 33.937400430759176
65 (5,) 230.0416201277115 46.0083240255423
70 (4,) 207.47647619960338 51.869119049900846
75 (6,) 389.7446815957917 64.95744693263195
80 (2,) 148.1140683360823 74.05703416804116
85 (5,) 338.6856269475073 67.73712538950146
90 (4,) 211.83179680175812 52.95794920043953
95 (6,) 253.24855615591525 42.20809269265254
```